# Stop Text Wrap in Word 2010 for an Equation Object

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting

In Word 2010, I have an equation object that wraps at the end of a line.  Is there a way to stop it from wrapping?  (Since it's an equation object, I can't just use a no break space like would be normal for text.)

Answer (score 5):

While Dominik's answer will work just fine, it will add a space in your equation next to the mathematical operator, which you will likely not want.

The way around it is to use the `No-Width No Break` special character. To do so:

- Go to where you want the equation not to break. This is typically immediately after an operator (`=,+,-,etc`).
- Click on insert → Symbols → More Symbols
- Pick the "Special Characters" tab
- Scroll to the bottom and insert the "No-Width Non Break" character

You can also add a shortcut key for it to simplify this process

Comment: You can do this by typing ‘‘200d’’ (or ‘‘200D’’), selecting it, and typing Alt+X. If the character to the left (i.e., to the left of the “2”) isn’t an “X” or a hex digit (“0”-“9” or “A”-“F”), you don’t need to select the “200D”.

Comment: I inserted this "No-Width Non Break" (NWNB) character after the > in an equation, A>0, which was wrapping to the next line in Word 2013, but oddly the character did not prevent the wrapping.  I have tried several variants, for example, adding one or several NWNB characters before and/or after the >, and none of them prevent the line break.  I also tried Scott's keyboard shortcut without success, and Ctrl+Shift+Space introduces too much space.  Any idea why the NWNB character does not work in (my copy of) Word 2013?

Answer (score 3):

Word (2010) wraps long equations (in display format) only before some [mathematical operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode), like `=, +, ∈` etc. (I know this from testing.)

To avoid the wrap, you can use a nonbreaking-space `Ctrl+Shift+Space` directly before the operator.

Answer (score 0):

The equation wraps when it won't fit in the margins of the page. Assuming there is enough room on the page for the equation, you can adjust either the margins, or the left and right indent.

- Select the equation by clicking on the handle at the left of it.
- Using the ruler drag the right indent to the right past the margin of the page
- If that doesn't give you enough space, drag the left margin to the left.

Alternatively, you can use the paragraph dialog to set the margins directly. This might be useful if you have a number of equations to fix this way and want them to all have the same settings. Dragging on the ruler in this case can be a bit fiddly.

- Select the equation by clicking on the handle at the left of it.
- Right click over the selected equation (not over the handle)
- Adjust the right indent (and left indent if needed)

Answer (score 0):

The No-Width Non-Break did not work for me but it was clutch for a solution that works.

1. Select the Script dropdown menu in the equations (labeled with an e^x)
2. Select the Left Subscript-Superscript option (which has a dotted box with a dotted left subscript box and a dotted left superscript box, like a left exponent)
3. Type the equation that you do not want to break in the bigger inline dotted box
4. In BOTH the left subscript and left superscript, type a No-Width Non-Break.

Pro-tip: Since Ctrl-Shft-Space is the Non-Breaking Space, I created the keyboard shortcut Ctrl-Alt-Space as the No-Width Non-Break.

Pro-tip: Create a macro within an equation that selects that Left Subscript-Superscript, then puts a Non-Width Non-Break into the subscript and superscript, and then goes into the box so that you can immediately type your equation. Then use your shortcut keys to run the macro every time. For my Windows computer, I press Alt-N-E-I to create an equation and then Alt-L-P-M-Enter to create the non-breaking equation box in less than 1 second.

Works like a charm.