# Stop Word Wrap in Word 2010 for an in-text Equation Object

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, equation-editor

> In Word 2010, I have an equation object that wraps at the end of a line. Is there a way to stop it >from wrapping? (Since it's an equation object, I can't just use a no break space like would be >normal for text.
>
> [Stop Text Wrap in Word 2010 for an Equation Object](https://superuser.com/questions/189078/stop-text-wrap-in-word-2010-for-an-equation-object)

I realize a very similar question has been asked already, however, the specific situation is different. The answer to the question above refers to equation objects which are simply too long to fit within the margins. The similar question is quoted and linked above for reference and to demonstrate knowledge of its existence.

---

I would like Word 2010 not to wrap my equation, which is within a paragraph. I would hope there would be a way for Word to treat it as an indivisible unit, so that it will start the next line if does not fit on the current line, as would any other word. Can this be done.

Note: Line breaks (i.e. Shift-Enter) are not preferable, as I must manually readjust them any time I adjust margins, paragraphs, styles, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just use nonbreaking-spaces `Ctrl+Shift+Space` instead of normal spaces.

The same answer applies to the question you've linked.